# How to retrieve the messages from a push data service on my server reliably?

Tags: python, architecture, push-notification, rabbitmq

On a third-party server there's a push data service. I need to be able to receive almost all the messages it sends by a python script running on my server.

I wonder, is it reliable? Can I just run my python script on my server and have it insert the incoming messages into db where I can access them later from a client application? Or should there be anything else more complex, such as one more level of something, involved?  Can I utilize RabbitMQ in that scenario something and is it really needed?

Comment: Yes, this should be completely possible. You can set up a Python process to receive messages and insert it into a database. You haven't specified what format/protocol these messages are being sent in, so it's difficult to point you to a specific library.

Comment: @jumbopap, xml or csv. So rabbitmq isn't needed?

Comment: @jumbopap, xml or csv. So rabbitmq isn't needed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplistic api set up with Flask that runs on `127.0.0.1:8001`, parses XML data with BeautifulSoup, and echoes the results.

note.xml:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/xml', methods=['POST'])
def recieve_some_xml():
    data = request.get_data()
    parsed = BeautifulSoup(data)

    to = parsed.find('to').text
    sender = parsed.find('from').text
    heading = parsed.find('heading').text
    body = parsed.find('body').text

    # do something with data, insert into db...

    return "Data sent was: %s, %s %s, %s" % (to, sender, heading, body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8001)
```

And when I send XML data to that address:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @note.xml -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/xml
Data sent was: Tove, Jani Reminder, Don't forget me this weekend!
```